# Getting uninitialized constant Student::Roo error while importing csv file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, roo-gem

I have an application on which I want to provide the feature to import the records from CSV and Excel file formats. I am using `roo` gem for it, but at the time of importing it gives the error "uninitialized constant Student::Roo".

Here is the code :

student.rb

```
def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    product = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
    product.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
    product.save!
  end
end


def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end
```

student_controller.rb :

```
def import
    Student.import(params[:file])
    #puts @session[:current_organization_id].inspect
    redirect_to students_path, notice: "Record imported Successfully."
  end
```

new.html.erb :

```
<%= form_tag import_students_path, multipart: true do %>
        <%= file_field_tag :file , :required=> true%> <br/>
        <%= submit_tag "Import" , :class => "btn btn-primary btn-block" %>
<% end %>
```

Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'sass', '3.2.19'
gem 'bower-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'devise'
gem 'roo'
group :development, :test do
    gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.0"
    gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
    gem "capybara"
    gem "database_cleaner"
    gem "selenium-webdriver"
end
```

student.csv : This is the test data for student.

```
enrollment_no,roll_no,address,father_name
11,21,test,test
17,21,test,test
18,21,test,test
19,21,test,test
20,21,test,test
22,21,test,test
23,21,test,test
24,21,test,test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, after @SKV comment: the correct name for CSV class is `Roo::CSV` and not `Roo::Csv`.

If the error persists, then it means that any of the `Roo` classes (`Roo::CSV`, `Roo::Excel`, etc) is not defined at this point in `Student` class. This probably means that, while you probably added the `roo` gem to your `Gemfile` and bundled, you need to `require roo` wherever you want to use the gem. This is mentioned in the [gem docs](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo#usage).

Add `require 'roo'` to the top of `student.rb` file and it should work fine:

```
# student.rb
require 'roo'  # <==== 

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: After using require 'roo' on the student.rb file i am getting the error "cannot load such file -- roo"

Comment: Can you show us your Gemfile? Did you run `bundle install` and restarted the server?

Comment: I have added the gem file and also i have run the bundle install and after that when i restart the server it gives the error 'cannot load such file -- iconv (LoadError)'.

Comment: I don't know which gem or code requires iconv in your case, but add this to your gemfile: `gem "iconv"` and then run `bundle install` and restart

Comment: Also, which version of `roo` are you using? That is shown in your bundle install console output. If it is not the last version, run `bundle update roo` and restart.

Comment: After running the bundle update roo, my roo version is updated to 2.0.1 but still i am getting the error 'uninitialized constant Roo::Csv'.

Comment: It's Roo::CSV, not Roo::Csv, and you don't need to require roo

Comment: Updated answer. You need to use `Roo::CSV` instead of `Roo::Csv` (thanks @SKR for noticing)

Comment: My problem is solved now but getting a new "error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" at the line header = spreadsheet.row(1).

Comment: That looks like another different question. I suggest you close this one and start a new one so we can help you better. You'll need to provide also info about the file you're uploading.

Comment: I don't have permission to post more than one question within 90 second so please continue with this only. I am importing csv file into it than it gives the error "error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" on this line "header = spreadsheet.row(1) " .

Comment: I also have add student.csv file above.

Comment: 90 seconds? No, please, new question. If you don't, this one will probably get deleted anytime for being confusing.

Comment: Ok! Also, if this question was solved, you could consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not Roo::Csv, it's Roo::CSV. So the code should like

```
def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end
```

btw, no need to do `require 'roo'`

Comment: still i am getting the error "uninitialized constant Roo"

Comment: This is not the problem. If there is a `::Roo` class defined, it will be found in the `Student` scope. If unfound, then rails looks for `Student::Roo` and fails if also unfound.

Comment: Dear @dgilperez please check before downvoting and making a comment. There won't be a class defined ::Roo, it's defined in global scope. The problem is actually, it should be Roo::CSV, not Roo::Csv

Comment: @SKR that is not what your answer says. You do can call `Roo` (the namespacing module) without `::` and it will be found, if required at the top of the file. The issue is not with adding or not adding `::` to the class instantiation. That's why my downvote.